# Unknown syntax to find input with class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found some code that does this in a validate function:

```
var $fields = $(form).find("input[required], select[required]");
```

What is this syntax doing? `input[required]`

In my HTML I have some inputs with required class, but they are not getting choosen, so I am unsure what is this trying to do.

Comment: Why the -1 ? Why is this question not correct?

Comment: Wasn't my -1 but I would suspect it was for lack of research probably.

Comment: Read up on jquery selectors or CSS selectors

Answer (score 4):

It's searching tags with set `required` attribute, like this:

```
<input required />
```

If you would like to search with `required` class, then use:

```
var $fields = $(form).find("input.required, select.required");
```

Answer (score 0):

That is called [has-attribute-selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

*Selects elements that have the specified attribute, with any value.*

---

To select elements with `class='required'`  you will need a selector like this -

```
"input.required, select.required"
```